Как связать 1с:УНФ со своим сайтом не 1с:Битрикс
Заказчик просит связать 1с:унф с сайтом.
Я никогда не работал с системой 1с:унф.
Есть ли возомжные интеграции с другими платформами, кроме 1с?
Можно ли написать frontend написать на angular и получать данные через get запросы на 1с?

дергать 1с с сайта вряд ли получится, во всяком случае, в управлении торговлей только 1с может стать инициатором обмена.

Если учесть, что конфигурацию 1С можно дописывать ручками, то можно что угодно.. хоть get, ws, etc
Вообще вас понимаю, связываться с битриксом дело хероев.. Единственное что смущает, если будет чистый фронт с апи на сам сервер 1С это как минимум не ок.. разве что вы об этом серьезно позаботитесь на стороне 1С)

@evgen_dev, не вводите людей в заблуждение. Легко реализуется с помощью публикации HTTP или Web сервиса.

@Sagittarius имелось ввиду стандартными средствами 1С, но да, написал не совсем корректно

@Sagittarius Я за 15 лет работы, ни разу не встречал директора, который был бы счастлив, когда их "святой 1С" доступен из вне. Обычно все сводится к тому, что дописывается нужный функционал в стандартный обмен, а на стороне сервера кастомный модуль, который это все дело принимает и обрабатывает. Но что бы 1С можно было дергать из вне, ни разу никто не соглашался. Возможно, у вас по другому, не настаиваю.

@evgen_dev, "имелось ввиду стандартными средствами 1С". Так разработка и публикация сервиса это возможности, предоставляемые платформой. В чём они не стандартные?
Про "доступ из вне", скажу, что есть те, кто этим пользуется. Просто вам не довелось увидеть.

@Sagittarius, обычно под "стандартными средствами", подразумевают возможности, которые предоставляются "из коробки", а когда что-то нужно кастомизировать/допиливать, то это уже никак не стандартные средства какого либо программного продукта. ИМХО. P.s. Предлагаю не продолжать этот "крайне полезный" диалог.


Есть ли возможные интеграции с другими платформами, кроме 1C?

Да, есть. Для вашей задачи можно использовать HTTP(REST) или Web(SOAP) сервисы.
HTTP-сервисы
Пример создания HTTP-сервисов на платформе "1С:Предприятие"
Web-сервисы
